# MIPS Assembly Calculator

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi please forgive me if my post is incorrect to the standards of StackOverflow as I am new. I am trying to make a calculator in MIPS Assembly language. My problem is that after I enter my integer values when running the program, the answer just prints out as an address. Thoughts on why I can't get the value to print?

Here is my code:

```
.data
getnum1: .asciiz "Enter your first number: "
getnum2: .asciiz "Enter your second number: "
getoperator: .asciiz "What type of calculation? (0 - add, 1 - subtract, 2 - multiply): "
result: .asciiz "The result is: "
num1: .word 1       #int 1
num2: .word 1       #int 2
operator: .word 1   #operator
answer: .word 1     #result

.text

main:   
li $v0, 4       #print string
la $a0, getnum1 #"Enter your first number: "
syscall

li $v0, 5       #read int
syscall         
la $s1, num1    #load num1 into s1
sw $v0, num1        #store value into s1 (num1) 

li $v0, 4       #print string
la $a0, getnum2 #"Enter your second number: "
syscall

li $v0, 5       #read int
syscall
la $s2, num2    #load num2 into s2
sw $v0, num2    #store value into s2 (num2)

li $v0, 4       #print string
la $a0, getoperator #"What type of calculation?..."
syscall

li $v0, 5       #read int
syscall
la $s3, operator #load operator into s3
sw $v0, operator #store value into s3 (operator)

la $s0, answer

beq $s3, 0, addition    #if operator is == 0, jump to addition
beq $s3, 1, subtract    #if operator is == 1, jump to subtract
beq $s3, 2, multiply    #if operator is == 2, jump to multiply

li $v0, 4       #print string
la $a0, result  #"The result is: "
syscall

li $v0, 1       #print int
la $a0, answer
syscall

addition:
add $s0, $s1, $s2  #add s1 and s2, store in s0
jr $ra  #return to last spot
subtract:
sub $s0, $s1, $s2  #subtract s1 and s2, store in s0
jr $ra  #return to last spot
multiply:
mult $s1, $s2 #multiply s1 and s2, store in s0
mflo $s0
jr $ra  #return to last spot
```

Comment: You're using `la` to put the address into `a0` when syscall 1 expects `a0` to contain the actual value.

Comment: But before I go into beq, I store the address of answer into s0, then in each branch label I store the result in s0 so how do I make it do the value? When I try: la $a0, $s0 it gives me an error

Comment: I would suggest that you probably want `lw $a0, answer` rather than `la`. Because, again, you don't want the **address** to be stored in `a0`

Comment: I changed it to sw $s0, answer right after the beq statements then changed it to lw $a0, answer right before the syscall at the end. Now I am just getting an answer of 0 each time

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what `la $s1, num1`, `la $s2, num2` and `la $s3, operator` are supposed to do, but they seem incorrect. Also, the `jr $ra` in `addition` et al will probably exit the program, because `beq` doesn't update `$ra`.